# How to manage request limited API calls

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api, rate-limiting

I am using tmdb API that has a new limit on requests which is 30 requests in 10 seconds per IP. I could track these calls by having a table in MySQL that holds the amount of requests per the last 10 seconds but how can I accomplish this with the different IP addresses?

The way my app works is:

1. request is made to the application server from a desktop app. Server side php then makes a search and returns data.
2. desktop app then makes a different call to app server and that in turns makes several api calls to tmdb (4-7) and other api's.

There can be anywhere from a few search requests to a few thousands in some cases. What's the best way to keep track and delay api calls to keep it below the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your server is sending requests to another server which has a rate limit, you'll need a global way to keep track of requests from your server, regardless of which client is doing requests to your server etc.

I would use a flat file, and save unix time and a delimiter for each request, and if the file contains ten of those, you've done ten requests, and you'll need to clean the file and remove any timestamp that is older than ten seconds, and that would give you the simplest form of a PHP rate limiter there is.

There are of course more advanced ways to this, but I'd start there, and make sure you test it so you don't loose your API access etc.

Comment: It seems to me like using MySQL for keeping track is simpler(as I already use MySQL heavily). Are you aware of a way to reset a MySQL field every 30 seconds for example without php (something a bit like auto increment except opposite and time dependent)? This would simplify my query to a simple increment per each API call.

Comment: I guess you are mistaking one thing. The number of requests you have to take care is that for your app server alone. It has NOTHING to do whether there are 100 or 1000 desktop clients hitting your app server. It is about how many requests your app server is hitting tmdb. So in short, there is ONLY 1 IP have to rate limit and thats of your app server.

Comment: If in future if you want to make calls from desktop client, then also in your client code you have to rate limit for that desktop ip stand alone, assuming no more than single desktop clients are sharing same IP.

Comment: You'll clean the database as you would a file, on every request you'll have to get the timestamps and remove the ones that are older than a certain time. You can't just remove them all every 30 seconds, as that would'nt work the same way. It's not just a matter of counting to ten, then waiting a few seconds etc. you need to know when every request was made to make sure the 10 per 10 seconds or whatever limit is'nt reached.

Comment: You could of course use MySQL for this, but I'm pretty sure that for just a few bytes of data a flat file will be a lot faster, and with many requests speed and simplicity is everything. You could also use a memory based storage, that would be even better.

Comment: Well my idea was to simply add 1 for every API request and have the database automatically reset this after 30 seconds, then the php would check if the number is below a certain amount and if so it would proceed with the request. This would be super simple or is there a flaw in my logic? The only other thing is that I'm not sure if MySQL can do the auto reset after 30 seconds.

Comment: Performance isn't a massive issue yet but there is a "MEMORY" storage engine in MySQL so that might be useful in the future...

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines of APC or MemCached, MySQL is a slow PITA IMO (ooh, look at all the acronyms), and I believe your logic to be flawed, but only you can really figure that out by testing it. Just create something where you can check the requests, and see if the ratio is kept with such a solution, and of course just send the requests to yourself or some adress that does'nt exist when testing.

Comment: I was thinking of MySQL events which would allow to run a a reset query  at given time periods but that's a recent development and my host hasn't updated to that version so I will go with your method, thanks.

Comment: I really don't know much about MySQL events, as I've never tried it, however cron tabs are always an option, But I would assume running a cron job every 30 seconds is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php sleep function to limit the rate at which you make requests. Or indeed use something like usleep function to make a halt by giving in number of microseconds by which you want delay.

Comment: Yes, but how do I keep track of this between requests? (eg. between calls to the php file) Also isn't there a timeout in php (it might start to matter with 7 requests and with large volume of requests before)?

Comment: You can maintain a log (by maintaining a sql table perhaps) for how many requests you issued within the time span and accordingly rate limit by halting using sleep method.

Comment: Ok, but then it will limit all users requests when I need to limit only per unique IP address.

Comment: The IP adress would be your server, not the users, if using PHP for the request.

Comment: You mentioned that your desktop app is making a request to app server which in turn hits tmdb servers. So in true sense, the only IP that would need to be rate limited would be that of your app server. It has nothing to do with your desktop client. Tell me if I have got your query right.

Comment: That's true, it is the server ip, I guess in a way it makes it simpler but also more limited in a sense. I might make the search queries directly from the app to increase the limit in the future... thanks.

Comment: I am glad if I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The [token bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) can do rate limiting. I made a threadsafe implementation with a shared storage for you: [bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket)

This example would throttle the application to a global consumption rate of 3 requests per second:

```
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\Rate;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\TokenBucket;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\BlockingConsumer;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\storage\PDOStorage;

$storage  = new PDOStorate("tmdb", $pdo);
$rate     = new Rate(3, Rate::SECOND);
$bucket   = new TokenBucket(30, $rate, $storage);
$consumer = new BlockingConsumer($bucket);
$bucket->bootstrap(30);

$consumer->consume(1);
$api->foo();
```