# PHP curl loop terminates early after 5th Iteration

Tags: php, curl, google-api

this is an issue I've run into before using curl. We do a mass data import at the beginning of the day for and part of that is geocoding some addresses. We use google's API to do this, so a simple curl loop (should) work, at least that's what I thought.

Here are my two functions: Note that the properties variable contains about 100 entries. However, no matter how many times I refresh, the loop **always** stops calling the curl function **after the 5th iteration**. Note that the loop *does not terminate, only the call to the curl function appears to be lost.*

```
function geocode()
    {
        $service_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=' . GAPI_KEY . '&address=';

        $properties = $this->listing_model->get_non_geocoded();

        if ($properties) {
            foreach ($properties->result() as $property) {
                $service_url .= urlencode($property->address . "," . $property->city . "," . $property->state . " " . $property->zip);
                try {
                    $search = $this->curl($service_url);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    var_dump($e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

function curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        unset($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

And of course the var dumps:

```
...previous (first) 3 entries...
string '14' (length=2)
object(stdClass)[116]
  public 'lat' => float #######
  public 'lng' => float #######
string '15' (length=2)
object(stdClass)[131]
  public 'lat' => float  #######
  public 'lng' => float  #######
string '16' (length=2)
null <-- ? Should be from curl
string '17' (length=2)
null <-- ? Should be from curl
string '18' (length=2)
null <-- ? Should be from curl
string '19' (length=2)
null <-- ? Should be from curl
```

Comment: You keep adding on extra parameters to the SAME url, so effectively you're doing `example.com?one`, `example.com?one&two`, `example.com?one&two&three`, etc...

Comment: Ah wow. I feel like an idiot, guess I've been looking at it too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the API's documentation found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/, it looks like you can only do five calls a second with a total of 2500 requests per day.

So now, I think your question is how to properly handle the rate limit and it looks like there are some good ideas here: [How to manage request limited API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237287/how-to-manage-request-limited-api-calls)

(Keeping track of every request, sleeping between every set of five requests, etc.)

Best of luck!

EDIT: Sorry! Didn't see that you had it solved. Figured that since the limit on the API was five and your loop was failing every five iterations, there was a correlation.